# Understanding Java's Reference classes: SoftReference, WeakReference, and PhantomReference

Tags: java, reference, weak-references, phantom-reference, soft-references

Can someone explain the difference between the three Reference classes (or post a link to a nice explanation)? `SoftReference` > `WeakReference` > `PhantomReference`, but when would I use each one? Why is there a `WeakHashMap` but no `SoftHashMap` or `PhantomHashMap`?

And if I use the following code...

```
WeakReference<String> ref = new WeakReference<String>("Hello!");
if (ref != null) {                 // ref can get collected at any time...
    System.gc();                   // Let's assume ref gets collected here.
    System.out.println(ref.get()); // Now what?!
}
```

...what happens? Do I have to check if `ref` is null before every statement (this is wrong, but what *should* I do)? Sorry for the rapid-fire questions, but I'm having trouble understanding these `Reference` classes... Thanks!

Comment: Why is there a `WeakHashMap` but no `SoftHashMap` or `PhantomHashMap` Excellent question, why I did not noticed this before..??

Comment: The `ref != null` check makes no sense. `ref` will never be `null`.

Comment: adding to the Q: `strongRef --> weakRef --> objA`. Now, will `objA` will be GCed or not, as it has an indirect ref from `strongRef`.

Answer (score 61):

The Java library [documentation for the `java.lang.ref` package](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html) characterizes the decreasing strength of the three explicit reference types.

You use a `SoftReference` when you want the referenced object to stay alive until the host process is running low on memory. The object will not be eligible for collection until the collector *needs* to free memory. Loosely stated, binding a `SoftReference` means, "Pin the object until you can't anymore."

By contrast, use a `WeakReference` when you don't want to influence the referenced object's lifetime; you merely want to make a separate assertion *about* the referenced object, so long as it remains alive. The object's eligibility for collection is not influenced by the presence of bound `WeakReference`s. Something like an external mapping from object instance to related property, where the property need only be recorded so long as the related object is alive, is a good use for `WeakReference`s and `WeakHashMap`.

The last one—`PhantomReference`—is harder to characterize. Like `WeakReference`, such a bound `PhantomReference` exerts no influence on the referenced object's lifetime. But unlike the other reference types, one can't even dereference a `PhantomReference`. In a sense, it doesn't point to the thing it points to, as far as callers can tell. It merely allows one to associate some related data with the referenced object—data that can later be inspected and acted upon when the `PhantomReference` gets queued in its related `ReferenceQueue`. Normally one derives a type from `PhantomReference` and includes some additional data in that derived type. Unfortunately, there's some downcasting involved to make use of such a derived type.

In your example code, it's not the `ref` reference (or, if you prefer, "variable") that can be null. Rather, it's the value obtained by calling [`Reference#get()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#get%28%29) that may be null. If it is found to be null, you're too late; the referenced object is already on its way to being collected:

```
final String val = ref.get();
if (null != val)
{
  // "val" is now pinned strongly.
}
else
{
  // "val" is already ready to be collected.
}
```

Comment: adding to the Q: `strongRef --> weakRef --> objA`. Now, will `objA` will be GCed or not, as it has an indirect ref from `strongRef`.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, @samshers, `objA` is eligible for collection as garbage. Pinning a `WeakReference` exerts no influence over the object to which that `WeakReference` points.

Comment: Does not having a strong reference up the chain make difference. Because for the `objA` to be garbage collected the weak reference has to be removed first right. And a strong reference is pointing to the weak reference making the weak ref ineligible to be GCed

Comment: No, the `WeakReference` does not need to be collected in order to allow `objA` to be collected. The `WeakReference` does not keep `objA` alive. Rather, it is a way to find `objA` while it's alive—without influencing that lifetime—and detect when the collector already took it away.

Answer (score 6):

A link: https://community.oracle.com/blogs/enicholas/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

`PhantomHashMap` wouldn't work very well as `get` always returns `null` for phantom references.

Caches are difficult, so `SoftHashMap` might not work as well as you might think. However, I believe Google's collection library contains a general reference map implementation.

You should always check that `get` returns non-`null`. (Note, that not checking that the `Reference` reference itself is not-`null`.) In the case of interned strings it always will, but (as ever) don't try to be "clever" about it.

Comment: The link has expired.

Comment: @MehrajMalik Link fixed.

Comment: adding to the Q: `strongRef --> weakRef --> objA`. Now, will `objA` will be GCed or not, as it has an indirect ref from `strongRef`.

Answer (score 3):

It should also be mentioned, as stated on the comment by Truong Xuan Tinh, here: http://blog.yohanliyanage.com/2010/10/ktjs-3-soft-weak-phantom-references/

That JRockit JVM implements weak/soft/phantom references differently than Sun JVM.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = new String("hello, world");
WeakReference<String> ref = new WeakReference<String>(str);
str = null;

if (ref != null) {                 
    System.gc(); 
    System.out.println(ref.get());
}
```

In this case, it will output null. The call to `System.gc()` is important here.