# What guarantees does Java/Scala make about garbage collection?

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, playframework-2.3

The Play framework has [`play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.3/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/Files.scala#L15-L42) that holds a reference to a `File`, and deletes it in the `TemporaryFile#finalize()`.

```scala
case class TemporaryFile(file: File) {

  def clean(): Boolean = {
    file.delete()
  }

  def moveTo(to: File, replace: Boolean = false) {
    Files.moveFile(file, to, replace = replace)
  }

  override def finalize {
    clean()
  }

}
```

I know that there are some issues with this, for example, you could fill up the entire disk without the JVM feeling the need to GC.

---

But here I ask about the "correctness" of a program, i.e. a program with no limit on disk space.

```scala
def foo() {
    val tempFile = TemporaryFile(new File("/tmp/foo"))

    val inputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile.file) // last use
    try {
        println(inputStream.read())
    } finally {
        inputStream.close()
    }
}
```

Could /foo/bar be deleted before I've read from the file? I don't use `tempFile` after `// last use`, so could it be finalized immediately after that?

Or what if it is passed as an argument to a function?

```scala
def foo() {
  val tempFile = TemporaryFile(new File("/tmp/foo"))
  bar(tempFile)
}

def bar(tempFile: TemporaryFile) {
  val inputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile.file) // last use
  try {
      println(inputStream.read())
  } finally {
      inputStream.close()
  }
}
```

---

If in the example above, `tempFile` may be removed before I am done using it, what is the correct use of `TemporaryFile` so that this does not happen?

Comment: Note that there is no relation between reading from the file and your `File` instance other than the name to identify the file system resource.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, correct.

Comment: Good question. And none of the answers address the issues that could happen when processing the `File` reference in an async Future block while the TemporaryFile object has already been collected... I suspect this to produce a bug on my app!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java objects are eligible for garbage collection once you no longer has a strong reference to the object. This is not dependent on if you "*use*" the object or not.

In this example,

```
def foo() {
    val tempFile = TemporaryFile(new File("/tmp/foo"))

    val inputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile.file) // last use
    try {
        println(inputStream.read())
    } finally {
        inputStream.close()
    }
}
```

`tempFile` is not eligible for garbage collection, and therefore finalization, until `foo()` is is no longer used. It's possible that objects that use members from `tempFile` may use it, and keep it ineligible longer than the last use inside `foo()`.

In this example,

```
def foo() {
  val tempFile = TemporaryFile(new File("/tmp/foo"))
  bar(tempFile)
}

def bar(tempFile: TemporaryFile) {
  val inputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile.file) // last use
  try {
      println(inputStream.read())
  } finally {
      inputStream.close()
  }
}
```

The result is the same.

In a minor variant (Java, I don't know Scala syntax well),

```
class Foo {
    List<Object> objects = new List<Object>(); 
    void foo(Object o) { 
        objects.add(o); 
    }
}

// ...

Foo f = new Foo(); 
f.foo(new Object()); // The object we just created is not eligible for garbage 
                     // collection until the `Foo f` is not used, because
                     // it holds a strong reference to the object.
```

Comment: @Dici http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809074/java-difference-between-strong-soft-weak-phantom-reference

Comment: @Dici I mean a reference that is your standard fare, no frills reference. A weak reference is one that does _not_ stop the GC from doing it's business. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

Comment: There are 4 kind of reference in Java,  strong, soft, weak and Phantom.  Further read :https://www.rallydev.com/community/engineering/java-references-strong-soft-weak-phantom.  Basically strong prevent object from being GC

Comment: _tempFile is not eligible for garbage collection, and therefore finalization, until foo() has returned_ is wrong. Since `tempFile` is not used after the access to its `file` field, the object it references immediately becomes eligible after that access.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't understand, `tempFile` is reachable until the method returns.

Comment: No, careful with the definition of _reachable_. [`A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1) After `tempFile.file`, the object referenced by `tempFile` is no longer reachable by any computation in the code above.

Comment: The javadoc says that `A newly-created object is strongly reachable by the thread that created it.`. Isn't `tempFile` a newly created object during all the execution of foo ?

Comment: Which javadoc? The term _newly created_ simply means that it's a new object. It's not a concept that spans over time.

Comment: In your quotation, the tricky word is **potential**. You can tell just by looking that `tempFile` won't be used again after some point, but does the GC knows it too ? I think it would make sense to say that any local variable will **potentially** be involved in a computation since is is accessible to the programer. Note that I'm careful with my assertions since I don't know much about it, I'm just discuting my intuitive point of view.

Comment: @dici Please reply with `@username`. That javadoc entry is simply stating that [Threads are GC roots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366211/what-are-the-roots).

Comment: @Dici Yes, the GC knows it too. The VM has access to the byte code and can tell that the only reference to that object is `tempFile` and `tempFile` is not used in the code after a specific line. If execution has passed that line, then it becomes eligible.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Interesting - you are of course speaking of the difference between the programmer _changing_ the method (say, appending a use of `tempFile`) versus the runtime behavior of the GC per specifications. The OPs question is about the latter. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

A local variable won't be finalized before the execution exits its scope. The GC doesn't finalize the objects that you don't use, **it finalizes the objects you cannot access anymore**, so in your example with tempFile, it won't happen before the foo() call is finished.

Comment: Scope has very little to do with GC. Scope defines where you can use the name of some entity. An object referenced by a local variable can be GC'ed even if the method (or other scope) containing the local variable hasn't ended.

Comment: I meant that a local variable cannot die **before** the execution exits its scope, because in that case it is clearly accessible. However, I do know that an object created locally can survive after the method containing it is ended. Is it clearer, or should I correct my answer ?

Comment: I'm saying the objects referenced by local variables **can** die before execution exits their (local variable) scope. [Scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) only deals with the validity of the use of a name in a program.