# Referencing a non-static method in a static class in Android - getSharedPref

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, static-members

I have following code :

```
  Context context = Activity.getApplicationContext();
             SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("AutoMsgSharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

            // Writing data to SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("key", "some value");
            editor.commit();
```

I have been trying to use SharedPrefs to store messages given in - "Conversation" class as in sample - https://developer.android.com/samples/MessagingService/index.html. But, I get "can not reference non-static method from a static class if I try to achieve it in constructor of "Conversation" class. So How do I resolve this?

Here is the screenshot of error if I update as suggested :

[image]

Comment: `Conversation` is static class?

Comment: yes : https://developer.android.com/samples/MessagingService/src/com.example.android.messagingservice/Conversations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

> Context context = Activity.getApplicationContext();

This line not return a valid Context for your application to call `getSharedPreferences`.

To call `getSharedPreferences` from non Activity,Service,... classes you should need to pass valid context from application component like from Activity,Service,..

To get `Context` in `Conversation` use Conversation class constructor which is already created in given example you will need to add one more parameter:

```
Context mContext;
public Conversation(int conversationId, String participantName,
                            List<String> messages,Context mContext) {
            .....
            this.mContext=mContext;
        }
```

Now use `mContext` to call `getSharedPreferences` method from `Conversation` class :

```
SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("AutoMsgSharedPrefs", 
                                                           Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the context no need to use Activity class. Change this code

```
Context context = Activity.getApplicationContext();
```

to

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: Pass the context in Constructor it self in "Conversation"

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: Activity class does not have a static method getApplicationContext(), because this method is non static, so you need to have an object instance. So call this method on Activity on Context instance.

Answer (score 1):

As *@ρяσѕρєя K* already pointed out you have to somehow grant your non-`Context` class access to your `Context` instance. For example through **introducing  a new parameter**.

```
public Conversation(int conversationId, String participantName,
                            List<String> messages, Context context) {
            .....

        }
```

*But keep in mind:*

It is **discouraged** to save references to long-life and heavy weight components like `Context`s in your classes because this [strong reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809074/java-difference-between-strong-soft-weak-phantom-reference) will exclude the `context` from the **garbage collection** and thus causing **memory leaks**.

**So** instead of storing your `Context` you can use it to initialize your `Conversation` object as you like and let the scope of the constructor take care of discarding the short-term reference to your `Context`.
If you should need a `Context` multiple times though, you could write a method which takes a `Context` instance as a parameter and call it to do the dirty work:

```
public void doStuff(Context context) {
          // do your work here
}
```