# No OutOfMemory Error for Strongly referenced objects - Why?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

From this post [Strong references never be garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809074/java-difference-between-strong-soft-weak-phantom-reference), With this understanding I assume if we create a infinite `Strong Reference objects` in memory then it must throw `OutOfMemory` error.

However, When I ran below dummy program it never through `OutOfMemory` error although I have created infinite objects in while loop.

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Test2 obj = new Test2();
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me understand if strong referenced objects are never garbage collected then how come there is no `OOM` error.

Comment: They're garbage collected as soon as they go out of scope; that is, immediately.

Comment: @shmosel- Did you read the post i attached ? It has 80 Likes on the answer , if you have know something else please elaborate in answer so that we can understand..please

Comment: Yes, what's your point? There's no such thing as a "Strong Reference object". Your code creates many objects, but only allocates a single strong reference.

Comment: @shmosel-- Yes understand it know with the help of Louis and piet.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't *keep* the strong reference to the object.  Each time you go through the loop, there's no longer any reference to the object created in the last iteration, and it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot...:) for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Objects are not garbage collected if they are *reachable from a GC-root-object via strong references*. In your example only one `Test2`-object is reachable from your thread at any time. The strong reference `obj` is updated each iteration and thus the previous `Test2`-object is no longer strongly referenced from anywhere and can be garbage collected.

If you want to create an OOM you might add the new objects to a `List` and keep them there.