# Does Java create another strong reference instance from get() of WeakReference instance

Tags: java, android, weak-references

For example,

```
WeakReference<Obj> weakObj = new WeakReference<>(obj);
Obj obj2 = weakObj.get()
```

In this example obj2 is strong reference type?

If yes means GC is not able to remove this reference until its parent get GCed?

Comment: Yes, it's a normal reference. If you `get` the object and keep a normal reference to it, then it will not be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

Default references are strong references

You have some more information in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809074/java-difference-between-strong-soft-weak-phantom-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Your `weakObj` is a `WeakReference`, and yes, `get()` returns a standard reference.